# ember.js panel update on route transition

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set up an ember.js application where I have two panels side by side on a page.  There's a link from one panel and when you click on it, it transitions to another route and the template for this route loads in the second panel -- but the first panel doesn't change.  I haven't been able to get this working.  I click on the link and the second panel loads, but the first panel is emptied.  Can someone point me to a place that might have some more info on how to do this -- or a simplistic jsbin.  Both would be incredibly helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your second panel would best be served by being a child of the first panel.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('panel1', function(){
    this.resource('panel12');
    this.resource('panel13');
  })
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mimoteba/1/edit